# android - how to mock a compiled dynamic library (.so)

Tags: android

To log how a given library, `libbinder.so`, is used, I would like to do the following:

create a mock `libbinder.so` that would effectively intercept calls from the function, then perform some logging action, then forward the call to the real `libbinder.so` which I would have renamed `libbinder.so.real`